# Zebra Printer: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004FFFF)

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, comobject, interopservices

We use the following code to print to a card.

```
byte[] image;

ZXPPRINTERLib.Job job = new ZXPPRINTERLib.Job();
job.JobControl.Destination = DestinationTypeEnum.Eject;

using (ZMotifGraphics graphics = new ZMotifGraphics())
{
    graphics.InitGraphics(0, 0, ZMotifGraphics.ImageOrientationEnum.Landscape, ZMotifGraphics.RibbonTypeEnum.MonoK);
    graphics.ColorProfile = string.Empty;
    graphics.DrawTextString(...);

    int imageSize;
    image = graphics.CreateBitmap(out imageSize);
}

int actionId;
job.BuildGraphicsLayers(SideEnum.Front, PrintTypeEnum.MonoK, GraphicTypeEnum.BMP, image);
job.PrintGraphicsLayers(1, out actionId);
```

It works on our development machines, but when we move to another test environment, we get the following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004FFFF): PrintGraphicsLayers Failed (65535) - Image processing error.
    at ZXPPRINTERLib.IJob.PrintGraphicsLayers(Int32 copies, Int32& actionID)
```

Comment: The company's support forum has an article about it.  Talks about zxp3raster.dll being the wrong bitness, typical deployment problem.  Best place to find help.  https://developer.zebra.com/thread/34951

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem is caused by the manner in which the `ZXPPrinter.dll` is registered.

As Hans points out in this [thread](https://developer.zebra.com/thread/34951), when registering both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the `dll` a folder with the `ZXP3Raster.dll` and a bunch of text files are created under `C:\ProgramData\ZXP Series Card Printer SDK\`.

Registering both versions of the dll, will cause the first to be overwritten.

Furthermore, my C# project's build `Platform Target` was set to build as `Any CPU`. The project ended up running as a 64-bit application, whilst referencing the 32-bit `ZXPPrinter.dll`.